# Igualar tamaño (width) en input y lista

Tags: css

Estoy intentando que un `<input>` y una lista tengan un mismo tamaño dentro de una página.

Para controlarlo, tengo ambos valores al 100%, pero al generar la lista de resultados, este es mas grande.

El `<input>` lo tengo dentro de un `<div>` por lo que cuando genero la lista, esta queda fuera y entiendo que por eso no me coge el tamaño correcto.

Estos son los valores que tengo en cada uno de los elementos:

```
.form-control {
  width: 100%;

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 100%;
```

Hay forma de poder controlar los tamaños en este caso?
Dejo subido el `<input>` para que se pueda ver el contenido **CSS** y una imagen con lo que sucede.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://139.162.206.138/bootstrap/autocomplete_v2/

gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El plugin, lo que hace al generar el listado del `autocomplete` es crearlo con el tamaño en píxeles que tenga su padre, en nuestro caso el `col-md-8`. ¿Qué es lo que ocurre? Que **Bootstrap** da a sus `col` un `padding` a la derecha y a la izquierda y este se suma a lo que ocupa el `<div>` en cuestión. Así que cuando se genera el listado este mide tantos píxeles de más como tenga en `padding` su padre.

Una manera de solucionarlo es quitándole ese `padding` al `col-md-8`.

**CSS**

```
.d-flex .col-md-8 {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo estas teniendo porque le estas añadiendo un padding al input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quitaselo y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: he comentado las lineas ```//padding: 10px 16px;``` pero sigue igual

Answer (score 0):

Puedes suprimir el tamaño sobrante al `dropdown-menu` restandoselo a la anchura del elemento. En este caso tiene `30px` de mas. por tanto podrias probar con:

```
.dropdown-menu{
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.